# How to use a list comprehension to square numbers within a start to end range?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Quiz:

> Use a list comprehension to create a list of squared numbers (n*n). The function receives the variables start and end, and returns a list of squares of consecutive numbers between start and end inclusively. For example, squares(2, 3) should return [4, 9].

My code:

```
def squares(start, end):
    squares = [value ** 2 for value in range(0, 11)]
    return [squares]

print(squares(2, 3))  # Should be [4, 9]
print(squares(1, 5))  # Should be [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
print(squares(0, 10))  # Should be [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Concise way to do it:

```py
def squares(start, end):
    return [i**2 for i in range(start, end+1)]
```

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def squares(start, end):
    squares = [value ** 2 for value in range(start,end+1)]
    return squares
print(squares(2, 3)) # Should be [4, 9]
print(squares(1, 5)) # Should be [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
print(squares(0, 10)) # Should be [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

gives

```
[4, 9]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Comment: Shouldn’t you return just `squares`, not `[squares]`?

Comment: indeed, I changed return [squares] into return squares

Comment: I would like to know why we added end+1

Comment: if you iterate over range(1, 2)  you get only one value: 1

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
def squares(start, end):
    squares = [value ** 2 for value in range(start, end+1)]
    return squares
print(squares(2, 3)) # Should be [4, 9]
print(squares(1, 5)) # Should be [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
print(squares(0, 10)) # Should be [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

output:

```
[4, 9]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```